# Multiple errors in ServiceStack Angular client

Tags: servicestack

We just started getting these errors when building our Angular project

```
 Error: node_modules/@servicestack/client/dist/index.d.ts:484:20 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

484     get completed(): boolean;
                       ~


Error: node_modules/@servicestack/client/dist/index.d.ts:484:22 - error TS2693: 'boolean' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

484     get completed(): boolean;
                         ~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@servicestack/client/dist/index.d.ts:484:5 - error TS1131: Property or signature expected.

484     get completed(): boolean;
```

using "@servicestack/client": "^1.1.17"

Answer (score 1):

We fixed by using "@servicestack/client": "1.0.59"